# Send email to a specific email using mailchimp

Tags: javascript, api

I know about the mail chimp JSON based API. However, I'm not sure if there is any way to use it to send an email to a specific recipient using javascript.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following steps you have to take:

1. I assume you already created a mail template in mail chimp
2. I am using mandrill to send mail through mail chimp. Install node package manager mandrill-api

   `npm install mandrill-api`
3. Call package in top of your code

   `var mandrill = require('mandrill-api/mandrill');
   var mandrill_client = new mandrill.Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');`
4. In your method define message variable 
   `var message = {
   "from_email": send_as_email,
   "from_name": send_as_name,
   "merge_language": "mailchimp",
   "global_merge_vars": null
   };`

   `message.to = [{
     "email":'SENDER_EMAIL',
     "name":'SENDER_NAME',
     "type": "to"
   }];`

   `message.subject ='SUBJECT OF MAIL';
   mandrill_client.messages.sendTemplate({
   "template_name":'NAME_OF_MAILCHIMP_TEMPLATE',
   "template_content": null,
   "message": message
   }, function (result) {
   //DO ON RESPONSE
   }, function (e) {
   //TRACE Your Error
   });`

Comment: This is a good answer. I would love to know how to do the same using PHP. Any ideas?

Comment: Can we use html instead of template name?